# How do we define equality in real numbers?

Tags: logic, soft-question, real-numbers

How do we define equality in real numbers? I know in logic we define equality by Leibniz's law.
   $$ \forall x \forall y[x=y \rightarrow \forall P(Px \leftrightarrow Py)] $$
But how do we define the set of all $P$'s for a system. For example for fractions we say $1/2$ and $2/4$ are not equal but in rational numbers they are. But it seems to me the set of all propositions that make sense about fractions and that of rational numbers are the same.

Comment: In first-order logic, one certainly does not define equality in the way you described.

Comment: so how do we define equality in first-order logic?

Comment: Equality is a primitive (undefined) concept. Certainly we state as an axiom that $x=y\to(Px\leftrightarrow Py)$ for any relational symbol $P$ of the language.

Comment: The most standard system is first-order logic with equality, in which equality is not defined, though there is an equality symbol, with some attendant axioms. And if we restrict ourselves to say ZF, again equality is an undefined notion, but the Axiom of Extensionality, which has some similarity to what you wrote, links equality with membership.

Comment: It's not necessary the bi-implication in your formulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You statment needs a little additional specification :

> in **second-order** logic it is possible to define equality by [Leibniz's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles) :
>
> > $∀x∀y[x=y→∀P(Px↔Py)]$.

In [Second-order Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) we interpret the universally quantified predicate variables as meaning “for every property of objects (in the universe of discourse)”.

The semantics for second-order logic is a little bit more "complicated" than the first-order one; but if we adopt the so-called "standard semantics" [see the related chapter into *SEP*'s entry, and compare with the chapter regarding *general semantics*], we have that :

> A key feature of the “standard semantics” [...] is that, for a one-place predicate variable $P$, the quantifier $∀P$ ranges over the entire power set of the universe of discourse.   We have seen that this feature gives second-order languages a high degree of expressive strength.

Thus, a predicate variable is "mapped" on a subset of the domain of discourse; i.e. the meaning of the (unary) predicate variable $P$ is a "property" of the objects of the domain.

If we consider a s-o language for the structure $\mathbb Q$ of the rational numbers and want to "apply" the above definitions to the example, in order to show that :

> the two fractions $1/2$ and $2/4$ are not equal

we have to find a predicate $P$ which "separates" them, i.e. such that $P$ holds for $1/2$ but does not hold for $2/4$.

I.e. we have to map $P$ into $P^* \subseteq \mathbb Q$ such that : $1/2 \in P^*$ and $2/4 \notin P^*$.

But the subset $P^*$ of $\mathbb Q$ is a set of rational *numbers*, and not a set of "names of numbers".

Thus, we cannot find such a $P^*$ ...

*Note*

Of course, assuming that when you say "the two fractions" you are speaking of the numbers... if instead you are meaning the *symbols* "$1/2$" and "$2/4$", of course they are different *names* for the same rational number (i.e. $0.5$).

But the fact that we can have more than one (in your example : two) "name" for the same object does not implies that the object "named" must be "splitted" in two.

Comment: Don't you need full semantics for this definition to work? (At least for monadic logic, then you can simply talk about singletons...)

Comment: No, it's just that unlike first-order logic, I came to learn that second-order logic doesn't have a standard interpretation (there are full semantics, Henkin semantics, as well syntactic forms like monadic second-order logic). So when you write that in "in second-order logic it is possible to define equality ...", I'm just asking which second-order logic you are talking about. Because there are many of them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is not how equality is *defined*. This is a property that equality has.

In modern first-order logic equality is primitive. We don't define it, we just know that two things are equal if and only if they are the same thing. So two numbers are equal if and only if they are the same number.

For example, $0.\overline 9=1$ because both of these are in fact the same number.

So what about $\frac12$ and $\frac24$? Why are they equal? Well, recall that when we say $x=\frac ab$ we really mean that $x$ is the unique number such that $bx=a$. And so we have that: $$x=\frac12\iff 2x=1\iff 2\cdot2x=2\cdot1\iff 4x=2\iff x=\frac24$$
Therefore the two fractional representations of $\frac12$ are the same. But why does it surprise us that there are several ways of writing the same number? It shouldn't, after all, $0$ is both the unique number such that $1-1$ equals to it, as well the smallest number such that $x^2=x$, and the unique rational number $x$ such that $\sin \pi=x$.

There are many ways of writing an expression which evaluates to the same number. And that's fine. But here's the kicker: expressions are not actual numbers, they are string in the language, and whether or not two expressions are equal may (or may not) depend on the interpretation of the symbols involved in these expressions.

So perhaps a better question would be "What determines if two expressions have the same value in $\Bbb R$", but that question is vague since it doesn't specify the language, and how it might be interpreted. And in different languages we may be able to express different things (e.g. compare what you can express in the language which only includes $\leq$ and what you can express in the language which also includes $0,1,+,\cdot$ but doesn't include $\leq$).

Comment: reading Peano axioms from Wikipedia it appeared to me as if the axioms #2 to 5 were the definition of equality in natural numbers and it led to the similar questions about the real numbers. And my def of equality is also from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Yes, yes, historically equality was not a primitive notion. But we are not living in the 19th century anymore. Not even in the 20th.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "We don't define it, we just know that two things are equal if and only if they are the same thing. So two numbers are equal if and only if they are the same number." Do you mean that we define two mathematical objects to be equal in such a way that the definition incorporates the idea of the "same thing"? E.g. the matrix equality definitions agrees with our notion of equality. Nevertheless we must define equality in order to assign truth values to our statements A=B (A and B are matrices).

Comment: @user599310: No, we don't *define* equality. Period. It is built into mathematics. You can think about this as fixing a Leibnizian congruence relation (i.e. an equivalence relation where any two equivalent objects can be interchanged in any formula), and then divide by this relation to get equality. However, as I repeat here, equality is sort of "built in into mathematics". And the assignment of truth simply relies on this. If you insist defining *everything* you'll soon find out that there is no solid ground *to anything*. Some things must be taken on faith.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But when someone asks what is equality we should be able to answer. I mean it must have a definition (irrespective of the fact that such a definition is more intuitive and less abstract/formal). So can we define it as "equal iff the same thing"?

Comment: @user599310: No. Some thing are not defined in terms of other things. Mathematics has atoms. It is somehow unusual when you first start studying mathematics (or even before), but that's true. Yes, we can define equality of *some* objects using other means (e.g. two sets are equal when they have the same elements, or two real numbers are equal if they are strictly larger of the same set of rational numbers). But that is not true *in general*. And when you unpack those "other definitions" you will often find that somewhere inside there's another notion of equality.

Comment: @user599310: The thing about "two things are equal iff they are the same thing" is that it *explains to us* what equality means. But it is not a mathematical definition per se, because "the same thing" is not a mathematical notion, unless you say that two things are the same if they are equal, in which case you end up with a circular argument.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the answer. So we can consider equality in maths as an a priori concept?

Comment: @user599310: As I keep repeating, yes.